# Get start date from Event Calendar wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, plugins

I'm working on an event website in Wordpress and I use this plugin: https://theeventscalendar.com/

All the documentation files say that I have to use tribe_get_start_date() to get the event date. So that's what I'm using in my custom loop.

```
$events = tribe_get_events();
if ( empty( $events ) ) {
    echo 'Sorry, nothing found.';
} else foreach ($events as $event) {
   echo get_the_title( $event );
   echo tribe_get_start_date( null, false, 'j F Y' ):
}
```

But the function tribe_get_start_date always gives the current date instead of the event date.

What can be the issue?

The ideal situation would be that the loop only shows the 4 upcoming events.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is due to you passing `null` to your `tribe_get_start_date` function, when  you might want to be passing `$event`.

```
$events = tribe_get_events();
if ( empty( $events ) ) {
    echo 'Sorry, nothing found.';
} else foreach ($events as $event) {
   echo get_the_title( $event );
   echo tribe_get_start_date( $event, false, 'j F Y' ):
}
```